# Why are convolutions and pooling described as layers in a network?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, convolution, max-pooling

Whenever I look at resources on convolutions and max-pooling in CNNs they always seem to describe these algorithms as being part of the network - a preliminary set of layers before the main computation. It just seems strange considering they have no learnable parameters and only need to be applied to a dataset once (at least in my understanding that's the case). Surely it is vastly more inefficient to run these algorithms every time a piece of input data comes up - especially if you are training multiple models or there is potential for input samples to come up in batches multiple times...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you specify what are the "algorithms" you refer to? Is it max-pooling or also the convolution operations? What is the "main computation"? Can you cite some resources? By the way, max-pooling is often used between convolutional layers, therefore it is part of the computational graph. There's no way to compute max-pooling without knowing the feature maps of the previous parameterized convolutional layer.

Comment: Sure yeah, when I say "algorithms" I am referring to the combination of max-pooling and convolutions in the way you describe - an alternating series of computing the convolution of input data with a given kernel, followed by a max-pooling algorithm - and by main computations I mean the feed through process of the dense layers with learning hyper-parameters.

Comment: Here is an IBM document which outlines the basics: https://www.ibm.com/topics/convolutional-neural-networks. They refer to convolutional & pooling layers, but why can't these be statically applied to the dataset beforehand - rather than being included in the network so that they are applied each feedthrough - it seems unnecessary since for a given input they will always compute the same output.

Comment: Convolutional layers do have learnable parameters/weights, the kernel and biases, so your claim here is incorrect.

Comment: Ah I see - that makes a lot more sense. Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems it was just based on a wrong assumption, which is now clarified in the comments.